# Transliteration in sed

Tags: bash, sed, terminal, command-line-interface

I'm trying to convert Arabic numerals to Roman numerals using sed (just as a learning exercise), but I'm not getting the expected output.

The sed manual says

> y/source/dest/
>   Transliterate the characters in the pattern space which appear in source to the corresponding character in dest.

Input

```
echo "1 5 15 20" | sed 'y/151520/IVXVXX/'
```

Output

```
I V IV XX
```

Expected output

```
I V XV XX
```

I've tried replacing first `X` with any character, and the output is the same for each, so I gather that `1` is mapped to `I` by the sed program. However, according to the description of the `y` command, shouldn't the program be transliterating character by character? How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the description. What `y` does is whenever any character from the left-hand side occurs in the input, replace it with the corresponding character from the right-hand side.

Specifying one character multiple times doesn't really make sense and I'm not sure the behavior of `sed` is defined in this case, although your version apparently takes the first occurrence and uses that.

To illustrate:

```sh
$ echo HELLO WORLD | sed 'y/L/x/'
HExxO WORxD
$ echo HELLO WORLD | sed 'y/LL/xy/'
HExxO WORxD
```

Fundamentally, your problem is that it's impossible to accomplish this task with just transliteration.

Your case illustrates that quite nicely: `15` is really `1` and `5` and `sed` has no way of distinguishing between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You already got the "why" answer, but FYI here's how to do what you wanted using a standard UNIX tool:

```
$ echo "1 5 15 20" | awk '
    BEGIN { split("1 5 15 20",a); split("I V XV XX",r); for (i in a) map[a[i]]=r[i] }
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i=map[$i] }
1'
I V XV XX
```

Comment: Thanks Ed for this excellent example of split and map functions of awk. I wonder if this could be extended to deal with general conversion of Roman to Arabic numerals. Every code I have seen is in Java, c++ etc.

Comment: @elmclose You're welcome. That sounded like something that'd show up in Rosetta Code so I took a look and there it is - the function `roman2arabic()` at https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Roman_numerals/Decode#AWK.

Comment: Thanks again Ed. This is exactly what I was looking for. Never knew about this site. Lots of hidden gems in there.